# How is overflow handled in word addition steps in Salsa20?

Tags: stream-cipher, salsa20

I feel like I'm completely missing something there. The quarter-round proceeds as follows:

```
b ^= (a + d) <<< 7;
c ^= (b + a) <<< 9;
d ^= (c + b) <<< 13;
a ^= (d + c) <<< 18;
```

So at each step, we're adding words a, b, c, d together. And at the end of 20 quarter-rounds, we add the current state matrix with the previous state.

What I don't see is how overflows are handled. If two words added exceed the value of a word, does it simply wrap around?

Comment: The additions are modulo $2^{32}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [Salsa20 page](https://cr.yp.to/salsa20.html) -

> Each modification involves xor'ing into one word a rotated version of the sum of two other words modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.

Adding two `uint32`s and ignoring the carry / overflow is equivalent to performing addition modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.